# How Can I Write a Postgres "if" Based on a SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, functions

If I have a function in PostgreSQL, I can validate its arguments (eg. a `username` argument) like so:

```
IF LENGTH(username) < 4 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Usernames must contain at least four characters';
END IF;
```

What I can't figure out is how to do the same thing with the results of a SELECT query, ie. something like:

```
IF LENGTH(SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username=username) > 1 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Username already exists';
END IF;
```

(And yes, I know PostgreSQL will give me an error without that line, but I want to have a friendlier error message.)

Is something like that possible in (Postgre)SQL, and if so can someone point me at the syntax (or an example of it) that I could look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but the subquery needs an extra pair of parentheses:

```
length((SELECT col FROM users WHERE ...))
```

One pair of parentheses is for the subquery, one for the function call.

The more readable way to write this is

```
(SELECT length(col) FROM users WHERE ...)
```